# Expected an assignment or function call (in class)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'm writing an application in React.
There is such a code -

```
  createCanvas(container) {
    if (
      this.width !== undefined
      && this.height !== undefined) {
        const canvas = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
        canvas.style.position = 'relative';
        canvas.setAttribute('width', `${this.width}px`);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', `${this.height}px`);
        const halfWidth = this.width / 2;
        const halfHeight = this.height / 2;
        this.yLine = canvas.appendChild(this.createLine(halfWidth, 0, halfWidth, this.height, '2px'));
        this.xLine = canvas.appendChild(this.createLine(0, halfHeight, this.width, halfHeight, '2px'));
        container?.appendChild(canvas);
        this.svgCanvas = canvas;
    }
  }
```

An error appears on this line - `container?.appendChild(canvas);`
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions
If you turn off the eslint check, then everything works
Tell me how to fix it?

I tried putting a return before this line, surrounding the function in ()

Comment: try changing `container?.appendChild(canvas);` to `if (container) { container.appendChild(canvas); }` - if that works, it could be that your eslint or other parser library is too old to understand the `?.` optional chaining syntax

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to use of optional Channing.

> container ?? container.appendChild(canvas);
> using  this will solve the issue

Comment: Why would that solve the issue?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).